# How to use a camel project as a library in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, spring-camel

I have a spring boot project that exposes a camel route, from this project I generate a jar that I want to use in other spring boot projects. However adding the jar as a dependency and trying to use the route doesn't get any output. How can I use the jar and call the route in my other projects?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Spring Boot project with a Camel route and you want to reuse it in other Spring Boot projects, you can follow these steps:

- Export the project as a JAR file: In your Spring Boot project with the Camel route, export the project as a JAR file. You can do this by running the `mvn clean install` command in the project directory. This will generate a JAR file in the target directory of the project.
- Add the JAR as a dependency: In your other Spring Boot project, add the JAR file as a dependency in your pom.xml file. You can do this by adding the following dependency:

  com.example
        my-camel-route
        1.0-SNAPSHOT

Make sure to replace the values with the correct ones for your project.

- Use the Camel route: To use the Camel route in your other project, you need to create a Camel context and add the route to it. You can do this by creating a class that extends `org.apache.camel.spring.boot.CamelContextConfiguration` and adding the route to the Camel context in the `afterApplicationStart` method. Here's an example:

  ```
    @Configuration
    public class MyCamelConfiguration extends CamelConfiguration {

        @Autowired
        private MyCamelRoute myCamelRoute;

        @Override
        public void afterApplicationStart(CamelContext camelContext) {
            camelContext.addRoutes(myCamelRoute);
        }
    }
  ```

In this example, `MyCamelRoute` is the class that contains the Camel route in your JAR file. Make sure to replace the class name with the correct one for your project.

With these steps, you should be able to use the Camel route from your JAR file in your other Spring Boot projects

Comment: Can the configuration be inside the lib itself?